# Abrir File Chooser o Gestor de archivos en una ruta especifica

Tags: java, archivo, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy usando File Chooser para seleccionar archivos desde mi software.

lo que quiero es que al abrir el gestor de archivos me abra en una ruta especifica por ejemplo: `c:/carpeta/alarmas.`
porque por defecto abre en DOCUMENTOS.

Este es el código que uso:

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser();
//solo puedo selecionar archivos(txt o musica o imagen pero no carpetas: no directorios
jf.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
//solo puedo seleccionar un archivo a la vez no varios a la vez
jf.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
//aqui filtro lo que quiero que se cargue
//si solo permito mp3 lo pongo o si solo admito jpj, primero pongo la descripcion del archivo y luego el tipo de archivo
//FileNameExtensionFilter filtro=new FileNameExtensionFilter("Descripcion de archivo","wav","Archivo Audio MP3","mp3","archivo imagen JPG","jpg");
FileNameExtensionFilter filter=new FileNameExtensionFilter("Archivo De Audio wav","wav");
jf.setFileFilter(filter);
//mostrar el gestor de archivos y no deja hacer nada hasta que se selcione el archivo o me salga con cancelar
jf.showOpenDialog(this);
//agarre lo que seleciona
File seleccion_ruta =jf.getSelectedFile();
//si la selccion es diferente de null , pasela a txt
if (seleccion_ruta!= null) {
    ruta_alarma_reservatxt.setText(seleccion_ruta.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

y como se muestra en la imagen es lo que quiero, QUE ME ABRA DIRECTAMENTE EN LA RUTA QUE LE INDICO.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para abrir tu `JFileChooser` en la ruta que tu quieras, puedes indicarle dicha ruta donde instancias el `JFileChooser`

Prueba a poner tu código así:

```
JFileChooser jf = new JFileChooser("C:\\carpeta\\alarmas.");
```